# Можно ли в imageview часто передавать изображения

Tags: java, android, graphics, android-imageview

Допустим Imageview принимает изображения, размером 30х30 px . думаю  нет разницы передаются они ему setImageBitmap() или setImageResource(), в том или ином случае  60 раз в секунду я сменять изображение не смогу. Не с проста ведь канвас сперва блокируется, потом рисуется и после разблокируется. Врядли наверно  не блокируемому Imageview можно так часто присваивать разные изображения. Не успело одно отрисоваться, как уже присваивается другое, наверно есть вероятность получить Null пока imageview занят отрисовкой. Или же в нативном коде Imageview тоже блокируется ,если ему присваивать изоюражение и только потом всё отображается?

Каким образом можно часто рисовать в ImageView (не считая канвас)

Comment: Т.е вы создали пустой проект, в разметку добавили ImageView, написали код меняющий картинку раз в секунду и он не работает?...

Comment: ну я пытался, так как учусь, то не мог правильно обратиться, то искал imageview до setContentView . В итоге написал и всё работает. Внизу в комментарии к ответу, я написал , почему был поставлен мной этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

ImageView не предназначен для частых отрисовок, а для вывода статического изображения на экран, но если так сильно волнует этот вопрос, то почему сами не попробовали написать простое приложение и проверить это на практике.

Comment: Дело в том, что я только начинаю изучать программирование и думал,что прочитав этот вопрос , кто то подтвердит мои опасения и скажет , что нельзя часто передавать в imageview изображение и мне не придется тратить время ,чтобы во-первых реализовать это, а потом искать точную причину почему оно не работает. Но так как подсказать четких не было, я это реализовал. 60 раз в сек передаю   в небольшой imageview изображения цифр (секундомер делал) и всё нормально работает, но я плохо понимаю почему это работает. Чем отличается принцип отрисовки на канвасе , от отрисовки в imageview?

Comment: канвас приходится блокировать ,чтобы отрисовать. может imageview тоже блокируется, но писать об этом вручную уже не требуется. Если так то всё ясно.